# How to simplify two nested findWhere in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Suppose I have an object like this:

```
var data = [
    {   
        "class": 101,
        "students": [
            { "name": "bob", "grade": 98 },
            { "name": "alice", "grade": 87 }
        ]
    },
    {   
        "class": 103,
        "students": [
            { "name": "mike", "grade": 73 },
            { "name": "bill", "grade": 77 }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a simpler way to do this using `underscore.js`?

```
_(_(data).findWhere({"class": 101}).students).findWhere({"name": "alice"}).grade // is 87
```

Comment: use a function predicate?

Comment: Oh you mean use `_.find()` with a predicate? I didn't even think of that. That should do it in one function.

Comment: I like your solution. I think it will be hard to get away from the double loop look of this problem. Maybe split it up for readability? `var students = _.findWhere(data, { class: 101 }).students; var aliceGrade = _.findWhere(students, { name: 'alice' }).grade;`

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
var student101 = _.findWhere(data, { "class": 101 }).students;
```

Above code gives you this
           { "name": "bob", "grade": 98 },
           { "name": "alice", "grade": 87 }

So doing so we get

```
_.find(_.findWhere(data, { "class": 101 }).students, function(num){ return  num.name  == 'alice'}).grade
```

Final Result 87

Comment: That's the same thing as using two `findWhere`, except it's inconsistent since you're using a `findWhere` first, then a `find`.